# Flutter Web back button

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

For some reason, on release mode, my Flutter web app is showing the wrong icon. Here is an example:

[image]

You can check it out yourself at https://emirsurmen.com.

I even overrid the `leading` in the AppBar but that did not work either.

My app bar:

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text("Work", style: GoogleFonts.inconsolata(color: Colors.white)),
        leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back), onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context), tooltip: "Back"),
      ),
```

Full project: https://github.com/MakufonSkifto/MakufonSkifto-s-Work

I want it to show the actual icon I gave, the back icon. Is this some kind of bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: seems to be some kind of bug. Maybe try to open an issue on github

Comment: I had a similar issue when I was adding a splash screen the splash screen was overlaying over the app in the release version. I upgraded the fluter version to 2.2.2 in my CD env and then build the app again this solved my issue. you try the same, delete all the previous build files then build again using the latest flutter SDK, if that resolves the issue then good otherwise raise a ticket in the flutter Github repo.